# Logrotate not working in Ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: codeigniter, logrotate

I have installed Logrotate in my system. 
My Log file name is like : log-2015-09-09.php
Here is my configuration in etc/logrotate.conf file :

```
/home/root/php/www/myProject/CI/application/logs/log-%Y-%m-%d.php{
        daily
        size 1K
        copytruncate
        compress
        rotate 1
        notifempty
        missingok
}
```

When i check status using :

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate/status
```

It did not show me anything about my logs and also did not delete or compress my log files.
Is there something wrong in my configuration that i need to change.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the directory/file name is the cause here. I'm not sure what you are tying to do with the `%` in there, but you can use wildcards instead like:

```
/home/root/php/www/myProject/CI/application/logs/log-*.php {
    daily
    size 1K
    copytruncate
    compress
    rotate 1
    notifempty
    missingok
}
```

You could also test the logrotate too using:

`logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf`

-d = Turns on debug mode and no changes will be made to the log files.

-f = Tells logrotate to force the rotation, even if it doesn't think this is necessary

Comment: I follow your instruction and check status using : logrotate -d -f /etc/logrotate.conf
I got following error :

rotating pattern: 
/home/root/php/www/myProject/CI/application/logs/log-*.php forced from command line (1 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs mailed to myemail@gmail.com
switching euid to 0 and egid to 104
error: error switching euid to 0 and egid to 104: Operation not permitted

Comment: Hi i can see now zip file(log-2015-09-08.php.1.gz) but these zips are not deleting. I want to delete these zips and there corresponding php file.

Comment: I am facing these same issues, zip files are not deleting by own.